# Why CSS Animation Producing gradient?

Tags: html, css

Why CSS Animation Producing gradient? Any way to remove the gradient effect? And how would you know what gradient it will produce without running code?

```
 0%,
100% {
    background-color: red
}
50% {
    background-color: yellow
}
```

Comment: can you post more of the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-color` is considered an [animated property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). To overcome the gradual change in color, you will need to use `steps()`.

```css
.some-class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: anim 1s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from { background-color: yellow; }
  to { background-color: red; }
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class"></div>
```